# Unit testing PODO constructor exceptions in dart

Tags: dart

This is my constructor:

```dart
Merchant(
  this._firstName,
  this._lastName,
  this._company,
  this._buildingNumber,
  this._location,
  this._city,
  String pin,
  String phone,
  String email,
  this._image) {
  _validatePin(pin) ? _pin = pin : throw pinFormatException;
  _validatePhone(phone) ? _phone = phone : throw phoneFormatException;
  _validateEmail(email) ? _email = email : throw emailFormatException;
}
```

I want to unit test this constructor. I want to test that the correct exception is thrown when the data validation fails.
I want the PIN to be a 6-digit number. So, this is the test I wrote for it:

```
test('pin must be a 6-digit number', () {
  expect(() {
    new Merchant(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, COMPANY, BUILDING_NUMBER, LOCATION,
        CITY, 1234567/*PIN*/, WHATSAPP_NUMBER, EMAIL, IMAGE_RESOURCE);
  }, throwsA(Exception));
});
```

I want to know how to properly use throwsA() function to ensure that the right exception with the right exception message was thrown.

This is the error I get from running the test above:

```html
Expected: throws ?:<Exception>
  Actual: <Closure: () => dynamic>
   Which: threw ?:<Exception: pin codes are 6-digit numbers>
          stack package:mnshi/model/merchant.dart 33:38                                              new Merchant
                /home/raveesh/MyCode/code/production/mnshi/test/cli_tests/merchant_tests.dart 27:21  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                package:test                                                                         expect
                /home/raveesh/MyCode/code/production/mnshi/test/cli_tests/merchant_tests.dart 27:7   main.<fn>.<fn>

package:test                             expect
test/cli_tests/merchant_tests.dart 27:7  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close! `throwA` actually takes another `Matcher`, not a `Type`.

Assuming you have something that extends `FormatException` you could write:

```
expect(() {
  ...
}, throwsFormatException);
```

If you don't, you could make your own sort of composite matcher:

```
final throwsException = throwsA(const isInstanceOf<Exception>());

...

expect(() {
  ... 
}, throwsException);
```

The reason for this is you could write different composite matchers. For example, here is one that checks that something is thrown that has a `.toString()` of `'Bad thing occured'`:

```
expect(() {
  ...
}, throwsA(predicate((e) => e.toString().contains('Bad thing'));
```

You can learn more about matchers here:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/test#asynchronous-tests
- https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/matcher/0.12.1%2B4/matcher/matcher-library.html